# Use SQL on In-Memory Data

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have two (or more) DataSets coming from queries from different databases and data warehouses. Now I need to merge these DataSets (e.g. JOIN, UNION ALL, aggregate functions, etc.) in a configurable way, preferable described in SQL syntax. 
Is there an efficient way to execute SQL on in-memory data? I collected the following approaches already, but none seems optimal for what I'm trying to do:

1. Define some proprietary language that can solve the problem and parse it. This is actually the currently existing solution, but maintaining and extending it is a lot of work.
2. Find some SQL driver that works on DataSets or other C# data structures. I couldn't find something like that.
3. Use e.g. SQLite to write the DataSets to tables (in-memory) and run SQL on them. I have to shovel all the data into the tables and then back again, though, so it probably won't be the most efficient solution. Also, we're usually using TSQL, so SQLite would introduce another SQL dialect.
4. Use SQL Server to write the DataSets to temporary tables and run SQL on them. More shoveling, but this time across process boundaries and with an already present SQL dialect.

Can anyone provide other approaches? Or maybe specific libraries for approach 2?

Comment: I'm not aware of a good solution for this, sorry; `DataTable` has some *very limited* support for things like filter and sort, but nothing you'd call real SQL

Comment: What you have to do with the data after merging, asking because may you can merge the data in the destination.

Comment: @MarcGravell As you said, those capabilities aren't anywhere close to real SQL. I don't think joining is possible at all.

Comment: @D.J. I'm working on a reporting backend. It is actually already in use and has about 150 different reports that are defined in an XML format and that it can execute and serve. The goal is to have as many reports of our reports as possible without any special implementation. It is possible to post process the data in the destination / on the consumer, but that would mean implementation effort per report and two (or more) places to have the logic of a report instead of one.

Comment: Then I think you have to go with option 4, use sqlbulkcopy to import data into a sql server  table  in a faster way. Then you can query your data for manipulation and filtration based on reports.

Comment: I would also suggest for linq if you can cast your dataset to lists. You can check the performance aspects of both approaches.

Comment: The downside of LINQ in my opinion is that I'd have to compile it at runtime which could pose a security risk. Also, SQL is known by much more people.